# Facebook post as page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I know this question was asked already often, but I have been trying to fix this problem for like more than 6 hours now and I could use a little help. Error Message: Insufficient permssion to post to target on behalf of the viewer.

I'm trying to post as page, my code so far:

```
var pageID = "myPage";
FB.init({
    appId: "myId",
    secret: "mySecret",
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
});

function postToFeed() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response) {
            var accessToken = "";
            var data = response.data;
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].id == pageID) {
                    accessToken = data[i].access_token;
                }
            }

            if (accessToken == "") {
                alert("You are not allowed to post.");
            }
            else {
                console.log(accessToken);
                FB.api('/' + pageID + '/feed', 'post', {
                    message     : "test",
                    link        : 'Link',
                    picture     : 'Imageurl',
                    name        : 'test',
                    to          : pageID,
                    from        : pageID,
                    description : 'test'
                }, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                    } else {
                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions,manage_pages,public_profile'});
}
```

When I echo my accessToken via console and copy the accessToken inside this code, it works perfectly. But that's not an solution because I want it to be dynamic:

```
function postToFeed() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        FB.api('/' + pageID + '/feed', 'post', {
            access_token: 'theAcccessToken',
            message: "I'm a Page!",
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions,manage_pages,public_profile'});
}
```

Comment: "I know this question was already asked often, but..."  Please explore SO to see if anybody else has answered the question first before you make a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this does not work? (not sure what you want to do with the "to" and "from" parameters, so i removed them)

```
FB.api('/' + pageID + '/feed', 'post', {
    message     : 'test',
    link        : 'Link',
    picture     : 'Imageurl',
    name        : 'test',
    description : 'test',
    access_token: accessToken
}
```

**The most important thing: You need `publish_pages` to post "as Page", not `publish_actions`.**

Btw, a small optimization:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].id === pageID) {
        accessToken = data[i].access_token;
        break;
    }
}

if (accessToken === "") {
    alert("You are not allowed to post.");
}
```

...always use typesafe comparison :)

Comment: "publish_pages" thats what i was looking for, thanks.